# Why Nexus's anonymous use get back as active?

Tags: nexus, anonymous

I'm facing a curious problem.

When I deactivate the anonymous user and disable the anonymous access,
after some minutes, it gets back in life (active, enabled).

```
2018-11-30 03:28:32,473+0000 INFO ...  ME ....anonymous.AnonymousManagerImpl - Saving configuration: AnonymousConfiguration{enabled=false, userId='anonymous', realmName='NexusAuthorizingRealm'}
2018-11-30 03:30:00,004+0000 INFO  [quartz-5-thread-16]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change WAITING -> RUNNING
2018-11-30 03:30:00,006+0000 INFO  [quartz-5-thread-16]  *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.quartz.internal.task.QuartzTaskInfo - Task 'Storage facet cleanup' [repository.storage-facet-cleanup] state change RUNNING -> WAITING (OK)
2018-11-30 03:30:07,325+0000 INFO ...  admin ....anonymous.AnonymousManagerImpl - Saving configuration: AnonymousConfiguration{enabled=true, userId='anonymous', realmName='NexusAuthorizingRealm'}
```

Is it automatic? or Is it actually some user logged in as `admin` and reset it?

Comment: Should not be automatic and there is an admin user.  I'm not sure so left a comment rather than an answer.  I can move if desired.  NOTE: If you want to be sure, you could (temporarily) remove the permissions of the admin user (assuming you have permissions=)).

Comment: It isn't automatic. If a logged in user initiated the action the user ID will be printed in column 5 of the nexus.log.  If there is a user ID, check the request.log for a corresponding request, you'll be able to see the IP address it originated from.